# Does it make sense to make a class in python when it would never get instantiated?

Tags: python, encapsulation

I have some methods in a file and all of them are defined in the global scope (a module). I did not bother to make a class because the class would never get instantiated and everything would still have to be accessed statically if I defined a class. Does it make sense to leave it as it is, or is it better design to make a class and make all my methods static? and why? 

 FYI: My script methods will get accessed by third party users.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Python is not Java, use module-level methods without worry.